# Need help to make Polygon Navigation style with transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

Can anyone please help me to make my Polygon navigation more accurate on different browsers because it works on Chrome but looks ugly on Firefox no support for IE also. Can anyone please help me add some jQuery / css3 code to make it work in at least Chrome & Firefox. suggest some code to make it better .. Thank You !
HTML Markup :

```
  <div id="left_rot"></div>
  <div id="str"></div>
  <div id="right_rot"></div>
  <div id="nav">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch" name="switch" class="chkbx">
    <label for="switch" class="pin"><span class="open">Open</span>
    <span class="close">Close</span> Menu</label>   
    <span class="link1"><a href="#link1">Link1</a></span>
    <span class="link2"><a href="#link2">Link2</a></span>
    <span class="link3"><a href="#link3">link3</a></span>
    <span class="link4"><a href="#link4">link4</a></span>
    <span class="link5"><a href="#link5">link5</a></span>
    <span class="link6"><a href="#link6">link6</a></span>
 </div>
```

fiddle link for css : http://jsfiddle.net/thekiddev/d8MLQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have work on your project, and changed 2 things.

I have changed your HTML, mainly to change the classes link1, link2, and so, to class link and ids link1 link2 link3.. That makes for a more compact code, since I can set shared properties for all the links.

Also, I have changed the way you position your triangles. Instead of setting positions for every one of them with top and left, I position all of them the same way. And then, I rotate them with the rotation center in the lower vertix of the triangle. That makes positioning them much easier.

The modified HTML is

```
<div id="nav">
    <!-- Option for Opening or Closing menu -->
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch" name="switch" class="chkbx">
    <label for="switch" class="pin"><span class="open">Open</span><span class="close">Close</span> Menu</label> 
    <!-- Links -->
    <span class="link" id="link1"><a href="#link1">Link1</a></span>
    <span class="link" id="link2"><a href="#link2">Link2</a></span>
    <span class="link" id="link3"><a href="#link3">link3</a></span>
    <span class="link" id="link4"><a href="#link4">link4</a></span>
    <span class="link" id="link5"><a href="#link5">link5</a></span>
    <span class="link" id="link6"><a href="#link6">link6</a></span>

</div>
```

And the CSS is

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background:#3498DB;
}
#nav {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 350px auto;
    position: absolute;
    text-align:center;
}
#left_rot {
    width: 200px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #E67E22;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:170px auto;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
    transform: rotate(60deg);
}
#right_rot {
    width: 200px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #E67E22;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:170px auto;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
#str {
    width: 200px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #E67E22;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:170px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
span {
    z-index:555 !important;
}
span a {
}
span a:hover {
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.link a {
    margin-left: -80px;
    top:-142px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:24px;
    text-align:center;
    background:transparent;
    color:#fff !important;
    padding: 0px;
    position:absolute;
    text-shadow:0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.50s;
    transition: all ease 0.50s;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
    height: 140px;
    width: 162px;
}
#link2 a {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
    transform: rotate(60deg);
}
#link3 a {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
    transform: rotate(120deg);
}
#link4 a {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
#link5 a {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg);
    transform: rotate(240deg);
}
#link6 a {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
    transform: rotate(300deg);
}
.link a:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
    width:0;
    height:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width: 140px 81px 0px 81px;
    border-color:transparent;
    border-top-color: #fff;
    margin:0px;
    z-index:5;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.55s linear;
    transition: all 0.55s linear;
}
#link2 a:before, #link4 a:before, #link6 a:before {
    border-top-color: #ECF0F1; 
}
.chkbx {
    display: none;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.pin {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    font-family: century gothic;
    background:rgba(252, 252, 252, 1);
    position: fixed;
    top: -300px;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #666;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease;
    transition: all 2s ease;
}
.chkbx:checked ~ .pin {
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(252, 252, 252, .5);
}
.chkbx:checked ~ .link a:before {
    border-color: transparent !important;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
    transform:rotate(180deg);
}

.close {
    display: none;
}
.chkbx:checked ~ .pin span.close {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
.chkbx:checked ~ .pin span.open {
    display: none !important;
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
footer h2, p {
    font-family: century gothic;
    color: #fefefe;
}
footer p a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #1f2f3f;
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/4qgUA/)

I have remover prefixed properties that aren't needed in modern browsers to keep the example short. It works ok in latest Chrom, Firefox and IE.